# How to export metadata from a file geodatabase as XML

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, metadata, arccatalog

I have a file geodatabase with ~20 layers and I would like an XML file for the metadata for each layer that I can send with my data.  I tried the "Export XML Workspace Document" tool but it only gives me one large file instead of individual files.

Is there a way to export individual XML layers of the metadata from a geodatabase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the export metadata tool
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/conversion-toolbox/export-metadata.htm

You will need to export every layer separately.

Comment: I don't have the tool in front of me but I assume like most tools I could run it as a batch process.  I have 4 geodatabases that are almost identical besides the location (each is a different US State) so I could see batch being useful to automate the exporting of metadata for all ~80 layers.

Comment: That should work. You could also write a python script using arcpy. First fetch all the layers, then use them as input for the tool one by one